# WIndows 10.module 'keyboard' has no attribute 'add_hotkey'

Tags: python, module, keyboard, attributeerror

I am trying to write programm which will react for keyboard hotkeys.

```
import keyboard

keyboard.add_hotkey('ctrl+e', lambda: keyboard.write('Hello'))

keyboard.wait()
```

First time it worked fine but after second time it stopped working and my console showed me this error :

```
**Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\python_projects\keyboard.py", line 2, in <module>
    import keyboard
  File "E:\python_projects\keyboard.py", line 4, in <module>
    keyboard.add_hotkey('ctrl+e', lambda: keyboard.write('Hello'))
AttributeError: module 'keyboard' has no attribute 'add_hotkey'**
```

My python is last-versioned. I tried to turn-off my antivirus system and re-install package. But it didn't help. I still have the same error. If you had this error and fixed this, write me what  I need to do. Thanks in advance

Comment: Change your file's name from `keyboard.py` to something else.

Comment: Thanks, bro. You are awesome. It helped me

Comment: As a future reference, naming your calling script the same as the module you try to use inside it is a recipe for shooting yourself in the foot.